# The request was aborted and The request was cancelled issue

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am getting failure issue at StreamUtil.Copy and the error as "The request was aborted and the request was cancelled" . I have tried by increasing the timeout atrribute of request eventhough it fails. Any suggestion it will be helpful. I have tried by passing the request in memory stream too and but no luck.

```
 string MIMEBoundary = "--MIMEBoundary633737556018130000";
            Uri urlUri = new Uri(url);            
            Logger.Debug("Preparing form post...");

            using (MemoryStream body = new MemoryStream())
            {
                this.GetPostData(body, MIMEBoundary, paramList);                
                body.Position = 0;

                HttpWebRequest myWeb = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlUri);
               //ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
               ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 10000;
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                myWeb.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                myWeb.KeepAlive = false;
                if (ignoreCertErrors)
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

                if (cookieContainer.Count > 0) {
                    Logger.Debug("Cookie container got cookies, len: " + cookieContainer.Count);
                    myWeb.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
                }

                if (proxyHost != null)
                {
                    Logger.Debug("Using proxyHost: " + proxyHost);
                    myWeb.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort.Value);
                }

                // force no proxy for private addrs
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                if (uri.Host.StartsWith("10.") || uri.Host.StartsWith("1.1.sample ip"))
                    myWeb.Proxy = new WebProxy();

               // myWeb.Method = "PS";
                myWeb.Method = type;
               myWeb.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
              //   myWeb.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
                myWeb.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
                myWeb.Timeout = timeoutMS;
                // myWeb.Timeout =-1;// System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
                if (credential != null)
                    myWeb.Credentials = credential;

                string auxContent = "multipart/form-data;";

                auxContent += "boundary=" + MIMEBoundary;
                myWeb.ContentType = auxContent;

                myWeb.Accept = "iso-8859-1";
                myWeb.ContentLength = body.Length;
               // myWeb.ContentLength =byteArray.Length;  
                Stream reqStream = myWeb.GetRequestStream();

                Parts.IO.StreamUtil.Copy(body, reqStream);

                //try
                //{
                //    body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                //    body.CopyTo(myWeb.GetRequestStream());
                //}

                //catch (Exception exp)
                //{
                //    Logger.Error("Publishing to Appstudio failed.", exp);

                //}
              //    myWeb.GetRequestStream().CopyTo(body);

          //   body.Write(
              //using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
              //{
              //    // Copy the response stream to the memory stream.
              //    myWeb.GetRequestStream().CopyTo(ms);
              //    ms.Write(myWeb, 0, myWeb.Length);
              //}

                //myWeb.GetRequestStream().CopyTo();
               /* string json_value = jsonSerializer.Serialize(data); //Body data
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(myWeb.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(json_value);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
                Stream responseStream = myWeb.GetResponse();
                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

                Parts.IO.StreamUtil.Copy(body, ms);*/

                HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWeb.GetResponse();
                return myHttpWebResponse;
```

stack trace as follows

at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at Parts.IO.StreamUtil.Copy(Stream input, Stream output) in C:\dev\parts\DotnetParts\IO\StreamUitl.cs